# Impact of empty data in ML models

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-preprocessing

Working on a project for my computational intelligence class at college doing machine learning models for crime hotspot predictions. Essentially what I am doing is laying a grid over the specific city and then using past crime data to determine which grids for the next month are likely to be hotspots. I have the data in the form I want it to be in with the the hotspot prediction column, as well as the features I want to use for these predictions.

Looking at data from the entire year of 2017 to predict the first month of 2018's hotspots. There a quite a few grid blocks within the city limits that are empty the entire year with not one crime occuring. So in my dataset it is an entire empty row.

My question is do these empty rows actually need to be removed when running the machine learning models? Would it have an actual impact to the model to leave the empty rows in the dataset? I see a lot of talk about having to "clean" data, I am just curious about the actually affects in my case.

Thanks ahead of time for any insight.

Comment: Haven't seen your data (a small example of which you should provide) but maybe you can replace missing data with 0.

Comment: That some grid cells where without crime certainly is part of the data, important information, and should not be removed. How to represent it depends on your data format, you didn't tell us, but a zero count is certainly information

Comment: Okay sounds good thank you all...my data is simple the target column (0 or 1) along with 4 features that are all normalized with values between 0 or 1. None of the data in the set will be null everything will contain at least a 0.